# GDB breakpoint on function arguments

Tags: gdb

Can we set a GDB breakpoint on a function such that it will break into only if the function argument matches the value specified?
Ex

```
int foo(int i) {
return i*i;
}

int main() {
  foo(0);
  ................
  foo(9);
}
```

How do I set a breakpoint on foo only when the argument i of foo is 5?

Comment: duplicate of [GDB conditional break on function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892091/gdb-conditional-break-on-function-parameter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, use "break if"

```
break foo if i == 5
```

If you have multiple variable if need to break on, just use classic `if` syntax :

```
break foo if i == 5 && j == 3
```

Comment: Thanks! what if I have to match multiple arguments in foo(i,j,k) ?

Comment: `break foo if i == 5 && j == 3`, as simply as that.

Comment: @kartik: use the syntax familiar from C ... I.e. `i == 5 && j == 3` (on occasion it is picky about parentheses being added and how).

Comment: @kartik No problem, be sure to validate the answer if it fits your needs.

Comment: @blue112 Yes waiting for 5 minute time limit to choose the answer.