# GDB conditional break on function parameter

Tags: c, gdb

I'm wanting to set a breakpoint on a function parameter if it is greater than a certain value. Dummy code below:

```
int main(void)
{
    uint64_t num = 123456;
    uint64_t x   = 847534;

    uint64_t other = (num*x) - (x/num);

    .... other stuff here (multithreaded stuff)

    calc(other);
}

void calc(uint64_t size)
{
    ...do some stuff with size
}
```

I've tried to set a breakpoint by:

```
(gdb) b calc if size == 852479
```

but it does not know what size is since it is a parameter I'm guessing. How would I break if the parameter equals a certain number. It is NOT an option to break on all the calls to this function because it gets called a billion times in the multithreaded environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set a conditional breakpoint in gdb, when char\* x points to a string whose value equals "hello"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183871/how-do-i-set-a-conditional-breakpoint-in-gdb-when-char-x-points-to-a-string-wh)

Comment: Have you tried setting the breakpoint on the first line of the function code?

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner I've looked at that 1 and it's not a duplicate because in the case of that code x (the variable in question) is assumed to be available by gdb to break on because it is a variable declared outside of a function. 

In my case this variable is the parameter of a function. I am successfully able to break on variables declared outside of a function but not able to break on parameters via conditional break

Comment: @Leeor That will work but this function gets called literally a billion times in a multithreaded environment and the error in question that I want to investigate happens after a variable amount of running time. So I will not be able to break on the first line on the function unless I want to keep pressing continue for hours (possibly days) :)

Comment: @Nick.D, I meant a conditional break

Comment: That conditional breakpoint command works fine for me (gcc 4.8.2, gdb 7.6.1-51.el7 on CentOS 7). I type it right after starting gdb, without running the target. What gcc/gdb versions and OS do you see this problem on?

Comment: are you using gdb on emacs, e.g. M-x gdb? It could be that its broken, try M-x gud-gdb instead - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662444/getting-gdb-to-work-with-emacs-24

Answer (score 9):

Assuming [x86-64 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) on GNU/Linux platform you could examine `%rdi` (64-bit) register directly to check function's first parameter:

```
b calc if $rdi == 852479
```

This allows you to break on function `calc` even if you don't have debugging symbols loaded (thus no code listing, i.e. by `list calc`).

Note that this method would fail if function is inlined by [optimizing compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler).

Answer (score 8):

from the `gdb` prompt:

```
break "file.c":100 if (size=852479)
```

or

```
break "file.c":100 if (size>852479)
```

here i am assuming you want the conditional breakpoint on line 100 and your src file is `file.c`

i.e if you want to break on the line that calls `calc`, then that would be line 100 - modify as appropriate (you would also have to substitute `size` with `other` in this instance)

if you used a line no. that was one of the 1st statements in the `calc` function then you would stick with `size`

Comment: The problem that I'm having is gdb is not aware of "size" before starting the program possibly because it's a parameter name and not a variable declared outside of a function. One thing that I am trying right now is to set a break point on the function, running the program, now gdb is aware of the size variable and now I'm doing a condition break on that variable. Example below


    (gdb) break file.c:calc
    (gdb) run
    Breakpoint 1, calc (size=48) at file.c:67
 in file.c

    (gdb) b if size = 852479  //This is where size is actually recognized by gdb
    (gdb) c

Comment: is gdb aware of anything *before* starting the program? 'other' is a variable that is declared and instantiated before the call to calc - therefore you should have no problem setting a conditional breakpoint on it (perhaps i am still misunderstanding the question here?)

Comment: size should have a "==" on it instead of a "=", should be this:   break "file.c":100 if (size==852479)

Answer (score 5):

If `break foo if arg1 == 14` doesn't work for some reason (I've encountered some functions/binaries where it does, and where it doesn't), you can try to substitute it with `commands`.

`commands` allows you to set some gdb commands that will be run each time breakpoint is hit. To achieve desired effect - a conditional breakpoint - you can do the following:

```
(gdb) b foo
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400633: file test.c, line 6.
(gdb) commands 1
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 1, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>silent
>if arg1 != 14
 >cont
 >end
>end
```

The execution will stop at breakpoint only if `arg1 == 14`.

The only drawback is that `silent` suppresses typical "breakpoint hit" message. You can remove `silent`, but then gdb will print the message even if breakpoint is skipped by `commands` script, which is undesireable if breakpoint is hit very often.

You can add some custom notification inside `command` script, though.