# How does built-in open() map to its C implementation?

Tags: python, c, python-internals

Trying to reason about the CPython source and was curious about the built-in `open()` method.

This method is defined in *_pyio.py* and returns a `FileIO` object, so I dug through source and found that (on Windows) there is a call to [`_wopen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open-wopen?view=vs-2019) (source [line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4c8f09d7cef8c7aa07d5b5232b5b64f63819a743/Modules/_io/fileio.c#L384)). Interestingly enough, I stumbled into *fileutils.c* where `_Py_open` is defined and subsequently `_Py_open_impl`. The latter makes a call to `open` (source [line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/fileutils.c#L1294)) which has a different signature than `_wopen` which I presume is referencing [`_wfopen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=vs-2019); however, below that there are `_Py_wfopen`, `_Py_fopen` and `_Py_fopen_obj`. Their comment lines seem to indicate that they are wrappers around the C functions provided from `#include`'s, so I know they're calling the originals and extending their functionality.

I'm not a C person by any means, mostly I can dig around code for debugging. This, however, has me lost. How are all these methods tied together (on Windows)?  So far I have:

```
open() -> io.py -> _pyio.py (_io) -> _iomodule.c -> ?
```

Not seeing where `_Py_fopen` or `_Py_wfopen` are called explicitly called (or used to wrap library functions) other than in `main.c` for startup file operations.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong implementation. The implementation in `_pyio.py` isn't actually used for anything but tests.

Comment: The `fileutils.c` stuff isn't relevant either. That's used by other stuff, not by the Python-level `open` function.

Comment: You can get some information by running a native code debugger and breaking at the underlying system call. On Linux/x86_64, the system call is called `open` and the file name is [passed in the register `$rdi`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892091/gdb-conditional-break-on-function-parameter/26892534#26892534) so: `gdb -ex "break open if ((char*)\$rdi)[0]=='w'" -ex run -ex backtrace --args /usr/bin/python3 -c 'open("wibble")'` gives me a native code backtrace for `open("wibble")`. How informative this is depends on how the Python interpreter was compiled.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica what do you mean it’s only used for testing? When I use`inspect.getmodule(open)` it returns *io.py*. So where is the implementation of the built-in `open` if not there?

Comment: @pasta_sauce: It returns `io.py`. *Not* `_pyio.py`. `_pyio.py` is only used for testing.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Inside `io.py`, the `open` method is imported from `_io`, which is where?

Comment: That's `_iomodule.c`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica And as I dive further into the internals of Python I find out more; that leads me to ask: where is `_iomodule.c`? I've downloaded a fresh Python executable and installed it. I can see `io.py`, but I don't see `_iomodule.c`. Presumably, its either compiled inside the interpreter or in `python3.dll` or `python36.dll`. If so, how does the process work to expose the builtin `open` from wherever that C file is?

Answer (score 1):

> The latter makes a call to open (source line) which has a different signature than _wopen which I presume is referencing _wfopen

What you mean is not clear but the call to `open` is referencing the [unix `open(2)` syscall](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), nothing to do with Windows.

> open() -> io.py -> _pyio.py (_io) -> _iomodule.c -> ?

_iomodule.c defines `_io_open_impl` which instantiates `PyFileIO_Type` from `fileio.c`.

That actually opens a file in `_io_FileIO___init___impl` which, after some faffing around, simply calls `_wopen` on windows and `open(2)` elsewhere: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_io/fileio.c#L383

Comment: So is the built-in `open` defined one the _iodmodule.c? It’s sequence matches that of what’s in _pyio.py.

Comment: Yes. The io module was originally implemented in pure Python. _pyio is that, and was largely deprecated when the module was reimplemented in C for performances, memory, … `_pyio` remains as a convenient way to test features & a copy for alternate implementations (e.g. a third-party implementation can just grab _pyio and get a working io module). The `open` builtin you normally get is the one which lives in `_iomodule.c`.